# Evolution of Homo Erectus to Homo Sapiens

Tags: human-biology, evolution

I just read an article on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homo_%28genus%29) and noticed that some similarities between *Homo Erectus* and *Homo Sapiens* in the "Comparative table of Homo species". My question is;

Is it possible to say that some members of *Homo Erectus* species
have survived up to now and they are living in modern world as members
of *Homo Sapiens*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not plausible that members of Homo erectus would survive and remain a separate species from Homo sapiens. For members of Homo erectus to survive implies that there wasn't significant interbreeding with Homo sapiens, which would require a significant population of Homo erectus.

There is some evidence that Homo erectus and other hominids interbred with Homo sapiens. So it is more likely that there may be some people with more genetic traits from Homo erectus than others. However, by significant interbreeding, there currently only exists a single species that may contain ancestors from multiple hominid species.

Comment: Not sure about _H.erectus_, but there is very strong evidence of interbreeding between _H.neanderthalensis_ and _H.sapiens_ as well as between the Denisovans and _H.sapiens_. It's likely that if the any of the _Homo_ species overlapped (in time and space) and were similar enough to produce fertile offspring, there would have been interbreeding between them.

Comment: Recently read [Why Does It Matter If Homo sapiens Had Sex With Neanderthals?](http://deskarati.com/2014/04/03/why-does-it-matter-if-homo-sapiens-had-sex-with-neanderthals/). That is an interesting viewpoint about my question.